# jQuery UI dialog works only once; opening for second time causes ViewExpiredException when submitted

Tags: jquery-ui, jsf-2, richfaces

I'm working in a Java EE aplication thats uses JSF2 and Richfaces 4. We decided that some interactions would be made using modal windows, and we chose Jquery UI Dialog with h:form, because we were already using Jquery UI in this project.

The Dialog is opened correctly, and submits the form, the submit is made using a h:commandButton and a4j:ajax. The h:commandButton stays hidden, and it is triggered by a dialog button.

Everything looks like perfect, but the dialog/forms just works once. If I close and open the dialog without refreshing the page I receive the message when submit the form:

> javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException:
>   viewId:/frontend/inicial.xhtml - /frontend/inicial.xhtml could not be restored

The JSF/HTML of dialog:

```
<h:panelGroup  id="dialog-nova-intercorrencia" styleClass="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
    <h:form id="frm-dialog-nova-intercor" prependId="false">          
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Paciente</td>
                <td>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="sel-intern-intercor" value="#{intercorrenciaController.novaIntercorrencia.internacao.internacaoID}"  styleClass="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{internacaoController.listInternacoesSelectItem}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Impacto</td>
                <td>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="sel-impacto" value="#{intercorrenciaController.novaIntercorrencia.impacto.impactoID}"  styleClass="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{intercorrenciaController.listaImpactosSelectItem}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>                        
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Data e Hora
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h:inputText value="#{intercorrenciaController.dataIntercorrencia}" styleClass="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 130px" />
                    &#160;
                    <h:inputText value="#{intercorrenciaController.horaIntercorrencia}" styleClass="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 70px" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Resumo</td>
                <td><h:inputText value="#{intercorrenciaController.novaIntercorrencia.resumo}" size="25" styleClass="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    Comentarios
                    <br />
                    <h:inputTextarea cols="30" rows="3" value="#{intercorrenciaController.novaIntercorrencia.descricao}" />
                </td>
            </tr>                
        </table>
        <h:commandButton id="btt-add-nova-intercor" action="#{intercorrenciaController.cadastrarIntercorrencia}" style="display:none">
            <a4j:ajax execute="@form" render="@form frm-dialog-nova-intercor panel-lista-intercorrencias" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The JS to create jQuery UI Dialog:

```
    $("#dialog-nova-intercorrencia").dialog({
        position: {
            my: "top top", 
            at: "top top", 
            of: window
        },
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 350,
        width: 400,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Cadastrar": function() {
                $("#btt-add-nova-intercor").trigger("click");
            },
            "Cancelar": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                $(this).find("input").val("");
                $(this).find("textarea").val("");
                $(this).find("select").val(0);                                
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            $(this).find("input").val("");
            $(this).find("textarea").val("");
            $(this).find("select").val(0);
        }
    });
```

Does anyone knows the reason I can execute the form in dialong only once and in the second time I get the message "view could not be restored" ?

Comment: Why don't you use RichFaces' own [`<rich:popupPanel>`](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&skin=blueSky)?

Comment: Earlier this project used JSF 1.2 and richfaces 3, and this time I judged that the Richface's modal window did not have all the features I needed, I do not remember exactly why.

Comment: @BalusC
thanks for comment and tips.
I think the text was not completely understandable. The problem is in the second submit and not in the second opening. Opens ok, one, two, three times, but when submitted after de first time I get the error message.

Comment: Yes, I already guessed that, but that's to me just a detail. The cause is clear, the JSF view state of the form isn't been updated on response of the submit. The solution is therefore obvious: make sure that the JSF view state of the form is updated on response of the submit. But I can't answer the exact solution from top of head as you are basically not using JSF directly, but trying to work around it with some custom HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: The problem was the JS that I was using to clean the fields before close the dialog:

   `$(this).find("input").val("");`

It was setting the input hidden javax.faces.ViewState in the form with null.

    `<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" value="" />`

Thanks @BalusC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the JS that I was using to clear the fields before close the dialog:

```
$(this).find("input").val("");
```

It was setting the input hidden javax.faces.ViewState in the form with null.

```
<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" value="" />
```